# macOS Mail is not threading by conversation with certain email replies

Tags: macos, email

There is the odd time an email escapes the thread of a conversation.  Not sure why this happens, the subject is identical.  It's even coming from an iPad, the headers are such should all be good.

Is there a way to 'force' add an email to a thread?